Is using accessibility live region mode a good solution for making Talkback read a certain textview on activity creation?
I have an native android app that has an activity with top bar having a back arrow and the title of the page.The activity is NFC based and the page instructs the user to tap their NFC enabled device with a NFC enabled card. There are a couple of text views instructing the user to tap their card on the back of the device. There is a timeout for the read card and a failure to tap a card before the timeout leads to an error.
I want to make this activity accessible. The issue is when this activity loads with Talkback on, the back button is in focus. And the user would have to navigate to the said TextViews to hear the instructions.
In the activity xml the visibility of these views is set to Gone initially and when the activity is created, the visibility is changed to Visible. The visibility or contents of this view doesn't change till there is a success in reading the data from the card or till there is some error. So I marked these TextViews as live region using android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite".
It works as  expected now when the screen loads, it reads the contentDescription of these two views and then proceeds to read the description of the back button. The accessibility focus stays on the back button the whole time.
I wanted to know if there are any caveats that I am missing that may lead to issues/errors or if this is not in compliance with the WCAG guidelines.
